# angularjs empty selection on dropdown menu

Tags: angularjs

I stumbled upon a problem with angularjs. I started learning it recently, but came upon an issue. I found a few people with the same problem, but they executed their coding very differently than me for the most part. So, I was able to put something together. In any case, this is what I am trying to do: in my form, the dropdown menu automatically chooses the first option, which is blank for some reason (something to do with angularjs default protection or something).

Before trying the code below, the code so far had been working correctly. Now, the last section of the form, with the stars as illustrated below, is always opened, no matter what when in fact it should only be opened when asked. Furthermore, because of the faulty coding, even that section does not properly work (because of the faulty coding). I believe that by correcting the main problem in the code below, all the minor problems are going to fix themselves in the process.

Anyhow, this is the HTML (followed by the js portion) below:

```
<blockquote ng-repeat="review in product.reviews">
                <b>Stars: {{select.stars}}</b>
                {{review.body}}
                <cite>by:  {{review.author}}</cite>
            </blockquote>

            <form name="reviewForm">

            <blockquote>
                <b> Stars: {{select.stars}}</b>
                <br/>
                <b> Review: {{review.body}}</b>
                <br/>
                <cite>by: {{review.author}}</cite>
            </blockquote>

                <!--<select ng-controller="starsController" ng-model="review.stars" name="stars" id="stars" style="margin-bottom:10px;margin-left:36px;width:350px;">-->

                <select ng-controller="starsController" ng-model="select" name="stars" id="stars"  ng-options="option.name for option  in typeOptions">
                    <optgroup label="Rate the product">
                     <option value="1 star" name="1 star">1 star</option>
                    <option value="2 stars" name="2 stars">2 stars</option>
                    <option value="3 stars" name="3 stars">3 stars</option>
                    <option value="4 stars" name="4 stars">4 stars</option>
                    <option value="5 stars" name="5 stars" selected="selected">5 stars</option>
                    </optgroup>
                </select>
```

JS

```
app.controller("starsController", 
function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.typeOptions = [
    { name: '1 star', value: '1 star' }, 
    { name: '2 stars', value: '2 stars' }, 
    { name: '3 stars', value: '3 stars' },
    { name: '4 stars', value: '4 stars' },
    { name: '5 stars', value: '5 stars' }
    ];

    $scope.select = $scope.typeOptions[4];

    }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="select" ng-options="option.name for option  in typeOptions"></select>
```

JS:

```
$scope.typeOptions = [
{ name: '1 star', value: '1 star' }, 
{ name: '2 stars', value: '2 stars' }, 
{ name: '3 stars', value: '3 stars' },
{ name: '4 stars', value: '4 stars' },
{ name: '5 stars', value: '5 stars' }
];

$scope.select = $scope.typeOptions[4];
```

[Pluker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Cvv10BWeuPHKNmQuJ5zV?p=preview)

[Select documentation on docs.angularjs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)

Comment: I played around with it, and modified some things after checking your suggestion and the link, but to no avail. It does exactly everything else it should do correctly (at least of what I can see), except one thing: Now, it currently selects the correct star, but that start should also appear on the top part, as part of the review. Furthermore, I changed review.star to select.star in the review portion (not sure it change made sense though). The jsfiddle, won't allow me to post it up :/